# How to improve performance of Multiple Select in React Material-UI for long lists?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to have a Material-UI multiple select for choosing countries, however with a long list of options ~200 I find the performance sluggish, particularly on slower machines (~1 second delay).

Is there something that can be done to improve this performance?

Below is the default multiple select example with person names switched for a country list.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-uh7k1

Comment: did you find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check [this](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/17001), it's an issue from material-ui github. They state that when you have a large set of items, you should use a [virtualized list](https://material-ui.com/components/lists/#virtualized-list) or the [native select](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/#native-select).